# Aligning & Justifying TextViews in ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, textview

**Let me start with an image:**

[image]

As you can see, it almost does what I need, except "Movies" drops to the next line -- which looks really horrible.  **Here is my XML code:**

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myMasterCat_Item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="99"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myMastCat_Cat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="MasterCat"
            android:textColor="#999"
            android:textSize="15sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I set it so it does not happen this way?

Comment: Try setting the weights to 98 and 2 or 97 and 3 instead of 99 and 1 perhaps.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work.  "Movies" is just an example.  Sometimes, a longer word or phrase may show up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/myMasterCat_Item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myMastCat_Cat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="MasterCat"
            android:textColor="#999"
            android:textSize="15sp" >
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also please note that if you use the weight attribute, you should set the width or height attribute to 0dp depending on which sizes you want to be affected..

Comment: Perfect!  Also, I am kicking myself on the 0dp, I usually do that!  Also, thought that if you use Layout Weight once, you have to use it for the entire layout. Guuess not.... This is great, thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped.. :) usually when you use weight=1 to one of the views then it will fill the remained space if used correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another solution as CustomView : https://github.com/merterhk/JustifiedTextView
Just add class to your src folder to use.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.view.View;

public class JustifiedTextView extends View {
        String text;
        ArrayList<Line> linesCollection = new ArrayList<Line>();
        TextPaint textPaint;
        Typeface font;
        int textColor;
        float textSize = 42f, lineHeight = 57f, wordSpacing = 15f, lineSpacing = 15f;
        float onBirim, w, h;
        float leftPadding, rightPadding;

        public JustifiedTextView(Context context, String text) {
                super(context);
                this.text = text;
                init();
        }

        private void init() {
                textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                textColor = Color.BLACK;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

                if (font != null) {
                        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/Trykker-Regular.ttf");
                        textPaint.setTypeface(font);
                }
                textPaint.setColor(textColor);

                int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
                w = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1);
                h = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

                onBirim = 0.009259259f * w;
                lineHeight = textSize + lineSpacing;
                leftPadding = 3 * onBirim + getPaddingLeft();
                rightPadding = 3 * onBirim + getPaddingRight();

                textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

                wordSpacing = 15f;
                Line lineBuffer = new Line();
                this.linesCollection.clear();
                String[] lines = text.split("\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                        String[] words = line.split(" ");
                        lineBuffer = new Line();
                        float lineWidth = leftPadding + rightPadding;
                        float totalWordWidth = 0;
                        for (String word : words) {
                                float ww = textPaint.measureText(word) + wordSpacing;
                                if (lineWidth + ww + (lineBuffer.getWords().size() * wordSpacing) > w) {// is
                                        lineBuffer.addWord(word);
                                        totalWordWidth += textPaint.measureText(word);
                                        lineBuffer.setSpacing((w - totalWordWidth - leftPadding - rightPadding) / (lineBuffer.getWords().size() - 1));
                                        this.linesCollection.add(lineBuffer);
                                        lineBuffer = new Line();
                                        totalWordWidth = 0;
                                        lineWidth = leftPadding + rightPadding;
                                } else {
                                        lineBuffer.setSpacing(wordSpacing);
                                        lineBuffer.addWord(word);
                                        totalWordWidth += textPaint.measureText(word);
                                        lineWidth += ww;
                                }
                        }
                        this.linesCollection.add(lineBuffer);
                }
                setMeasuredDimension((int) w, (int) ((this.linesCollection.size() + 1) * lineHeight + (10 * onBirim)));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawLine(0f, 10f, getMeasuredWidth(), 10f, textPaint);
                float x, y = lineHeight + onBirim;
                for (Line line : linesCollection) {
                        x = leftPadding;
                        for (String s : line.getWords()) {
                                canvas.drawText(s, x, y, textPaint);
                                x += textPaint.measureText(s) + line.spacing;
                        }
                        y += lineHeight;
                }
        }

        public String getText() {
                return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
                this.text = text;
        }

        public Typeface getFont() {
                return font;
        }

        public void setFont(Typeface font) {
                this.font = font;
        }

        public float getLineHeight() {
                return lineHeight;
        }

        public void setLineHeight(float lineHeight) {
                this.lineHeight = lineHeight;
        }

        public float getLeftPadding() {
                return leftPadding;
        }

        public void setLeftPadding(float leftPadding) {
                this.leftPadding = leftPadding;
        }

        public float getRightPadding() {
                return rightPadding;
        }

        public void setRightPadding(float rightPadding) {
                this.rightPadding = rightPadding;
        }

        public void setWordSpacing(float wordSpacing) {
                this.wordSpacing = wordSpacing;
        }

        public float getWordSpacing() {
                return wordSpacing;
        }

        public float getLineSpacing() {
                return lineSpacing;
        }

        public void setLineSpacing(float lineSpacing) {
                this.lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
        }

        class Line {
                ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
                float spacing = 15f;

                public Line() {
                }

                public Line(ArrayList<String> words, float spacing) {
                        this.words = words;
                        this.spacing = spacing;
                }

                public void setSpacing(float spacing) {
                        this.spacing = spacing;
                }

                public float getSpacing() {
                        return spacing;
                }

                public void addWord(String s) {
                        words.add(s);
                }

                public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
                        return words;
                }
        }
}
```

To use:

```
JustifiedTextView jtv= new JustifiedTextView(getApplicationContext(), "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ");
LinearLayout place = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.book_profile_content);
place.addView(jtv);
```